# Using array values to find files in a directory?

Tags: php

I have an array whose values are image names:

```
Array
(
    [rocks] => rocks.jpg
    [stone] => stone.jpg
    [bird] => bird.jpg
    ...
)
```

I want to scan 3 directories which are all in the same folder and match any images that match any of the array's values. The directory structure is like:

```
images
    nature
    animals
    misc.
```

I know about `scandir()` but am unsure of how to account for more than one directory. I eventually want to copy these matched images into a new directory. Would this be possible with PHP?

Any ideas or examples would be very helplful.

Thanks.

Comment: You could maybe directly use the underlying OS commands. For example `find . -name 'rocks.jpg'` (and execute that via `exec()`)

Comment: @feeela: There is no need for what you suggest, you can use `glob`. And therefore it remains 'OS independent'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `file_exists` function in PHP. Something like this:

```
$directories = array('nature', 'animals', 'misc.');
$found_images = array();
foreach ($image_names as $image) {
    foreach ($directories as $dir) {
        if (file_exists('images/' . $dir . '/' . $image) {
            $found_images[] = 'images/' . $dir . '/' . $image;
        }
    }
}
```

After this, `$found_images` will contain paths to all the images that were found.

To copy the file to another directory just use `copy`:

```
foreach ($found_images as $image) {
    copy($image, 'DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/' . basename($path));
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can deal with an item that has more than one image?

Comment: Also, although this works, why am I getting the error `Warning:  copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [glob](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.glob.php) to find your files, though you will be somewhat limited to the current structure.

For example:

```
$files = [];
foreach($filenames as $filename) {
 $files = array_merge($files, glob('images/*/'.$filename));
}
```

The glob will search for anything matching '$filename' inside any subdirectory of images. If you want to go deeper than this you have to create a recursive function.

Comment: Exactly, the `glob` function is what he is looking for.

Comment: This is a decent solution, though I guess it's worth mentioning that of course this will find images in any subdirectory, so if you wanted to limit it to those subdirs mentioned in the OP for example (I'm not sure of the intention) something else might be more suitable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great for me ... but any thoughts on how to copy the images within `$files` into a new directory?

Comment: @user3142418: Use the [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use two nested loops for this:

```
foreach(array_values($images) as $img) {
    foreach(array(
        'images/nature',
        'images/animals',
        'images/misc.'
    ) as $path) {
        if(file_exists("$path/$img")) {
            echo "file $path/$img exists" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will load all the files inside directories (Recursive) into the array

```
$FILES = array();

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    global $FILES;

    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.$ff))
                listFolderFiles($dir.$ff.'/');
            else{
                $FILES[] = $dir.$ff;
                if(in_array($ff, $my_array))
                {
                    copy('source_dir'.$ff, 'destination_file');
                    // do your stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

listFolderFiles('your_dir');
```

:) enjoy!